# Windows 8 Enterprise Lock Screen Change

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

Does anyone know how to change the Windows 8 lock screen, on the Enterprise version. All the instructions I seem to find only work on Pro or other versions of the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the November 2012 Update, MS added a GPO to manage the Lock Screen:

**[Win8: How to Manage the Lock Screen Image on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2787100/en-us)**

> The update “Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 cumulative update:
>   November 2012” adds functionality to the Control Panel group polices
>   that allow an administrator to designate a lock screen image on their
>   Windows 8 and Windows 2012 computers. This setting lets you specify
>   the default lock screen image shown when no user is signed in, and
>   also sets the specified images as the default for all users (it
>   replaces the inbox default image) Some restriction apply. See the
>   Restrictions section below.
>
> The new group policy is named **“Force a specific default lock screen
>   image”** and can be found in this path in the group policy editor:
>   **“Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Control
>   Panel\Personalization”**

Apply this GPO to get your custom image.

Comment: Absolutley perfect! Thank you for your help and time.